# I can't see the parameters to filter my query in Swagger on web api netCore

Tags: swagger

mi controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
        
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll([FromQuery] QueryObject query)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);   
    }
    try
    {
        var stocks = await _stockRepository.GetAllAsync(query);

        var stockDto= stocks.Select(s => s.ToStockDTO());

        return Ok(stocks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

then my Repository is:

```
public async Task<List<Stock>> GetAllAsync(QueryObject query)


 {
    

     var stocks = _context.Stocks.Include(c=>c.Comments).AsQueryable();

     if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.CompanyName))
     {
           stocks= stocks.Where(s=>s.CompanyName.Contains(query.CompanyName));      
     }

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Symbol))
     {
         stocks = stocks.Where(s => s.Symbol.Contains(query.Symbol));
     }

     return await stocks.ToListAsync();
 }
```

and my query objet with the parameters of filter is:

```
public class QueryObject
{
   
    public string? Symbol { get; set; } =null ;

   
    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }=null ;
}
```

my archive Program.cs is:

```
using api.Data;

using api.Models.Repository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//This section below is for connection string 

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});




// Add services 

builder.Services.AddScoped<IStockRepository, StockRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommentRepository, CommentRepository>();


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Configurar el JSON serializador para evitar ciclos de referencia en las respuestas JSON
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});


//

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{


    // Habilitar Swagger UI
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();


    app.MapControllers();


    app.Run();
```

"What could be missing for me not to be able to visualize my filter parameters?

I need help because I can't visualize my parameters on Swagger through a .NET Core web API."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3wfj.jpg)